# Check number of documents in each Alias in Elasticsearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch, indices, aliases

When I run this query:

```
GET http:localhost:9200/_cat/indices/INDEX-NAME?pretty
```

I get the following details:

```
green open INDEX-NAME j-0NlK8iTSzODRquUdjvZVg 1 0 10130216 17363 1.3gb 1.3gb
```

How to get similar details for an Alias of that index. Basically I am interested to check which of the aliases have the documents and which are empty.

I tried the following, but it is not of any use.

```
GET http:localhost:9200/_cat/aliases/ALIAS-NAME-*?pretty
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what aliases are linked to what index, you can use [_cat/aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-alias.html) which returns information about currently configured aliases to indices, including filter and routing information.

The results are similar to:

```
alias  index filter routing.index routing.search is_write_index
alias1 test1 -      -            -              -
alias2 test1 *      -            -              -
alias3 test1 -      1            1              -
alias4 test1 -      2            1,2            -
```

Note that you **won't** get information about the index they are associated since an alias **is not an index**, but a reference. Additionally, an index can has associated more than one alias.

You won't get information like `pri.store.size` or `store.size` with the alias. If you want to have information about the index they are associated to, keep using [_cat/indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html).

Hope this is helpful! :)